# Calculus prequisites book

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request

Everytime I try read a calculus textbook I find that my books (serge lang and gelfand's )didn't cover a subject well  (like say minimum of a quadratic polynomial)  ...I need a recommendation for a short and concise calculus book or pre-calculus that cover deely any subject needed to understand say Spivak's calculus or Courant 's Introduction to calculus and analysis...Any help would be appreciated ,thanks.

Comment: I don't see why minimum of a quadratic polynomial is a topic which needs to be discussed in depth in a calculus book, this should be an example or two at most - calculus will give you a method for finding the minimum of functions in general (I am referring to the necessary condsition that the derivative at the minimum/maximum is $0$)

Comment: I know ...Courant's book has a bit about a quadratic polynomial minimum in his talk about cauchy schwarz inequality ,it bugged me a bit .

Answer (score 0):

I have found that many of my students have a great deal of success with The Calculus Lifesaver by Banner. You can find it here http://press.princeton.edu/video/banner/